# Not able to hit controller when submitting Spring form

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring 4.2.0 with hibernate. I am trying to submit a jsp spring form which includes a date field to my controller. But I am not able to hit my controller and it is throwing me the below exception:

```
Field error in object 'loginDetails' on field 'dateOfBooking':
rejected value [2018-02-09]; codes
 [typeMismatch.loginDetails.dateOfBooking,typeMismatch.dateOfBooking,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch];
arguments
[org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
codes [loginDetails.dateOfBooking,dateOfBooking]; arguments [];
default message [dateOfBooking]]; default message [Failed to convert
property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
'java.util.Date' for property 'dateOfBooking'; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
[java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Date] for property
'dateOfBooking': no matching editors or conversion strategy found].
```

Below is my jsp code, bean and controller code.

This is my bean for table booking which includes a date field:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date dateOfBooking;
```

This is my controller code which is not getting hot for no reason:

```
@RequestMapping("/bookingTable")  
public ModelAndView bookingTable(@ModelAttribute("loginDetails") BookingTable bookingTable,HttpServletRequest request,ModelMap model) throws ParseException{
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    //Doing something here
    return new ModelAndView("bookingDetails");  
}
```

Please help me on this. I have been trying to do this for long. But could not.

Comment: Can you try adding an @InitBinder to your controller?
Eg: https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-validator-with-initbinder-webdatabinder-registercustomeditor-example

Comment: Thank you so much..It worked

Comment: Cool.. please accept the answer posted below. hope it will help someone with the same question

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding an @InitBinder to your controller?

To customize request parameter data binding, we can use @InitBinder annotated methods within our controller.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/InitBinder.html

Eg: https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-validator-with-initbinder-webdatabinder-registercustomeditor-example